# HTML <p> and <span> questions

Tags: css, html

How can I force the following HTML code:

```
<p><span></span></p>
```

.. to use vertical space?
if the span has a character, or a space, the vertical space is occupied.

Any way to do it with CSS?

Comment: Set a height on the span or p? not quite sure what ur asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
p span { display: block; height: 1em; }
```

However, you should put a class on that span, so it doesn't affect everything else.

EDIT: `inline-block` would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-height on the paragraph:

```
p { min-height:1.3em; }
```

However, IE6 does not support the min-height property... I don't have older versions of IE here, so I cannot test this but in modern browsers min-height works just fine. The value 1.3em represents the height of one line of text.