# How to provide default font height or content when <p> or <span> has no characters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, height

This started with one question similar to this one in here:
[HTML <p> and <span> questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826393/html-p-and-span-questions) .

And ended with 3... I want to understand why the following happen. Starting with this example:

> A `<p>` element without any special CSS rule on it has no text
>   when the page is loaded, therefore `height:0`. Due to javascript
>   operations in the page, it starts having characters, thus the height is
>   set to the default `font-size`, which allow us to see the text.

1. How can I assure that this `<p>` has always the same height (with or without text inside it)?
2. Why does using `em` in width affects a `<p>` and not a `<span>` like this:

```css
p,span {width: 1em}
```

```html
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
<span>this a span</span>
```

3. Although I understand that in W3C a "[`span` element is a generic wrapper for phrasing content that by itself does not represent anything.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html), my intention is to make it represent something... And since it's usage inside paragraphs is so often, why CSS cannot affect its height/width in the same way a `<p>` is affected?

I am answering to the first question with what I figured out, but I am not marking it as accepted - I am looking for an answer coming up with reasons that justify the usage of a particular solution.

I will only edit my question/answer if something is wrong or specific suggestions are made in order to do so.

Comment: In your example code, both the `span` and `p` have the SAME height right now. The difference visually comes from the `p` having a built in `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 2**

The width behavior of `p` versus `span` is due to the CSS specification for the `width` property.

`width` does not apply to non-replaced inline elements (`span`), so `p` being a block level elements, takes on the width value.

Note that, if you apply `display: inline-block` to a `span`, then the width is recognized since an inline-block is not a non-replaced inline element.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property

**Question 3**

HTML provides two generic, vanilla-flavored elements, `div` which is a block-level element, and `span` which is an inline element. `span` can be used within any element, be it `p`, `li`, `td`, `i` and so on.  If you want a `span` nested in a `p` to have a particular styling, you can define a specific CSS rule to enable the styling that you need.  If you want `p` like behavior with respect to width, padding, and margins, then you can specify `display: inline-block`.  The HTML specification does not specify a generic inline-block element, probably because no member of the specification group saw a need for it.

Keep in mind that the default styling of HTML elements is browser dependent, so in theory, a browser's default style sheet could have a rule for `p span`, but as far as I know, such an implementation does not exist.

**Question 1**

To prevent an empty `p` tag from collapsing to zero height, I would use a `:after` pseudo-element to insert a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` has the hex code `0xa0`).

Note that since the `span` is an inline element, its height will not collapse to zero because the height of an inline, non-replaced element is determined by the `line-height` property (`height` is ignored), so you don't need to add the non-breaking space UNLESS you want an empty space to have non-zero width.

```css
p, span {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
p:after, span:after {
  content: '\a0';
}
```

```html
<h4>Empty p</h4>
<p></p>
<p>p tag with text.</p>

<h4>Empty span</h4>
<span></span>
<span>span tag with text.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions below provide a default height to a `<p>` without text and an attempt to simulate empty content in a `<span>`:

### A

Using CSS, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp):

```
 p,span {height: 1em}
```

Will set the height:

> Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font).

```css
p, span {height: 1em}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p>Above there's a ghost paragraph</p>
<span></span>
<span>To the left there's NO visible trace of a span</span>
```

### B

Using only HTML, placing a space (`&nbsp;`) inside the `<p>` (so it actually does have a character):

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Above there's a ghost paragraph with a space</p>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span>To the left there's a span with a space</span>
```