# How can I remove a CSS style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want remove some style in bootstrap, this is a example:

test.html:

```
<div class='span1'></div>
```

bootstrap.css:

```
span1 {
  width: 60px; 
}
```

and I want to remove the `width` style, and add `min-width: 60px` style

I do this:

add `test` class in html:

```
<div class='span1 test'></div>
```

In the css:

```
.test{
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

But how can I remove `width: 60px` in `bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 4):

You can reset the width using `auto`:

```
.test{
  width: auto;
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

Working example:

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

span.test {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">
  span!
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers really resets a previous CSS rule... They just add a new one (when the width is set to `auto` or `inherit`, a different rule is created: the former property adjusts, the latter uses the parent's element as reference), and `span` is not the best element to [understand why the width is not affected (check the answer to "Question 2" to understand why)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628799/1326147).

Here is the proof using both `p` and `span`(["inline non-replaced elements" like span "**the `width` property does not apply**"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-width)):

```css
p, span {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}
p.test-empty {
  width: '';
  min-width: 60px;
}
p.test-auto {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 60px;
}
p.test-inherit {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  p without classes EXAMPLE
</p>
<p class="test-auto">p -> width: auto EXAMPLE</p>
<p class="test-inherit">p -> width: inherit EXAMPLE</p>
<span>span without classes EXAMPLE</span>
<br>
<span class="test-auto">span -> width: auto EXAMPLE</span>
<br><span class="test-inherit">span -> width: inherit EXAMPLE</span>
```

However, after rereading the question, there is **no mention** of a `span` element. What *nataila* refers instead is a `class="span1"` in a `div` element defined in **bootstrap.css**. Therefore, answering the question:

> how can I remove `width: 60px` in **bootstrap.css**?

You can do this by:

- defining a new CSS rule that is more specific than the **bootstrap.css** rule (e.g.: `.span1.test{width:auto}`);
- or you can redefine `.span1` after calling/invoking **bootstrap.css** (`.span1{width:auto}`).

The [`auto` property will adjust the element to the surrounding context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471874/1326147), thus in this case the `width` will be extended in order to use the entire space available of the `#container`:

```css
div:not(#container) {background-color: red;color: white;margin-bottom: 5px;font-size:11px}
#container {width: 500px}
.test-350 {width: 90px;min-width: 60px}
.span1.test-150-specific {width: 100px;min-width: 60px}
/* from bootstrap.css */
.span1 {width: 60px}
.test-210 {width: 110px;min-width: 60px}
.test-0 {width: 0;min-width: 60px}
.test-auto {width: auto;min-width: 60px}
.test-inherit {width: inherit;min-width: 60px}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="span1">
    Bootstrap.css default span1
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-auto">
    width: auto EXAMPLE
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-inherit">
    width: inherit EXAMPLE
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-0">
    .test-0 is defined with width:0 but, due to min-width, it actually has width=60px
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-150-specific">
    .test-150-specific is defined together with .span1, thus width=150px
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-210">
    .test-210 is defined after .span1, thus width=210px
  </div>
  <div class="span1 test-350">
    .test-350 is defined before .span1, which means it will get span1's width, thus width=60px
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the other rules are applied due to specificity or due to precedence, and if `min-width: 60px` is defined and `width` is under 60px, the element will remain with 60px!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset width by assigning `inherit` value:

```
.test {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.test{
  min-width: 60px;
  width:auto;
}
```

Should work like charm :)